# What happens to milliseconds since epoch when daylight savings time begins/ends?

Tags: time, timezone, epoch

Milliseconds since epoch represents the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since 1970.  At the instant before daylight savings time ends, or when we set the clocks back to 1:00 from 2:00, do the milliseconds since epoch fall back as well, or do they continue?

**Another question:**  If I live in California, US, which is on Pacific (Daylight/Standard) Time, is the milliseconds since epoch the same there as it is in, say, New York, on Eastern (Daylight/Standard) Time?

Comment: The only thing that disrupts continuity in [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) are [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Answer (score 12):

The milliseconds since epoch are not influenced by timezones and daylight saving time (daylight saving time just changed the timezone with -1 / +1).

The milliseconds/seconds since epoch are (always?) in UTC (or GMT + 0).

Comment: Yes - It is *always* based on UTC, excluding leap seconds.

Comment: @MattJohnson: What does it mean for milliseconds since epoch to "include" or "exclude" leap seconds?

Comment: @Mehrdad - Consider 1972-07-01T00:00:00.000Z. Since 1 leap second had just occurred, one might expect the milliseconds to be 78796801000, but no - it is still represented by 78796800000. One can think of this either as leap seconds being excluded in the calculation, or being included or absorbed into the value.

Answer (score 5):

Milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970 00:00:00 **UTC**) aren't affected by daylight savings and timezones as J. van Dijk mentioned.

To answer your 2nd question explicitly, which i think is important to understand UTC itself: if 2 people call `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Java or `new Date().getTime()` in Javascript at the same time, one of them being in California and one of them being in New York they should get the same number of milliseconds.